# Fix Cube Root Calculator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

```
cube_Num = float(input(" X: "))
cube_Pow = 0.333
cube_Root = cube_Num**cube_Pow
print(" Result: " + str(round(cube_Root)))
```

Now if i enter 216 it gives me ans 6 which is correct but if i enter 215 it gives 6 again and i know becuase im using round off function as im raising power to 0.333 which is about 1/3.Is there a way to get actual cube root of numbers like 215 in decimals ?

Note that perfect cube root answers are correct only if i use round off function. I want perfect cube roots to be integers and not floats while non perfect cube roots to be in decimal forms.

like 216 = 6
and 215 = 5.9

Comment: Cube root of 256 is 6.34960420787 , not 6. I think you meant 216.

Comment: I am unsure of what the issue is. It seems that the only reason you are not getting the result as a float is because you round the result, `cube_Root`, which you acknowledge in your question. Why are you rounding it if you do not want the rounded result?

Comment: If you want decimal, why you are using round function? Also make that: ```cube_Pow= 1/3```. And no, there is not a way to get actual cube root of numbers like 255 in decimal because they are irrational.

Comment: Guys i mean 216 and 215 and if i dont round off 216 gives 5.9 something not exact 6 thats the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly there is not a way to get actual cube root of numbers like 255 in decimal because they are irrational. Secondly, 6x6x6 is equal to 216, not 256. Thirdly, if you want decimal numbers, why are you using round function? Also use `cube_Pow= 1/3`.
Finally output of both 256 and 255 is 6 because you are rounding numbers like `6.329`. And this is the code you may use:

```
cube_Num = float(input(" X: "))
cube_Pow = 1/3
cube_Root = cube_Num**cube_Pow
print(" Result: " , cube_Root)
```

> Note that perfect cube root answers are correct.

No, not always.

```
>>> 216**(1/3)
5.999999999999999
```

Edit: Okey, I wrote that and it is working right for small perfect cubes like 216, 27 etc:

```
import math
cube_Num = float(input(" X: "))
cube_Pow = 1/3
cube_Root = cube_Num**cube_Pow

floor = math.floor(cube_Root)

if floor**3 == cube_Num:
    print(floor)
elif (floor+1)**3 == cube_Num:
    print(floor+1)
else:
    print(cube_Root)
```

Comment: thats why i put round off to convert 5.9999 to 6.

Comment: That is problem about floating numbers (I mean, have you ever tried that```0.1+0.2``` ?). You cant do much thing about that. If you round any input, how can you output decimal numbers of 255?

Comment: so this means that perfect cube root calculator cant be build using python ?

Comment: Friend, you cant find perfect cube root of all numbers in any device or language, because some of them irrational. If you mean 5.999999 , it is problem about floating numbers, not about any language or python. I recommend you that:https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi02tutzvDlAhWEgVwKHRvTCoUQyCkwAHoECAkQBA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPZRI1IfStY0&usg=AOvVaw1r_KDskeIZ3JZjpJDBDIag

Comment: If you wonder how calculation app in your computer work, it is rounding 5.99999 to 6 too. Or maybe it check 1 to 6 while 6**3 is being equal to 216. But computer may calculate 6**(1/3) a bit false anyway.

Comment: Thanks Dude! I was thinking how my smartphone converts 216 to 6 but 215 to 5.9. I think i must learn more.Maybe simple arthematic operarions are not the only thing i need for that.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark me as answer :D

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compute exact cube roots of integers, then you have to do integer arithmetic; there is no way around this. Floating point arithmetic is not precise enough to give correct cube roots, even when the correct cube root *is* exactly representable as a float. The problem is that `1/3` is not exactly representable as a float, and the `**` operation on floats doesn't make strong guarantees about precision (unlike the basic arithmetic operations, which do guarantee correct rounding).

So here's a solution using the binary search algorithm, which works purely by integer arithmetic, and always gives exact results: the result of `int_cube_root(x)` is guaranteed to be the integer part of the true cube root, i.e. the true answer rounded towards zero.

If you want exact answers for perfect cubes, but approximate decimal answers for non-perfect cubes, you can replace the final line `return sign * b` with `return sign * x ** (1/3)`.

```py
def int_cube_root(x):
    if x >= 0:
        sign = 1
    else:
        x = -x
        sign = -1

    a, b = 0, x
    while a <= b:
        m = (a + b) // 2
        m3 = m * m * m

        if m3 == x:
            return sign * m
        elif m3 < x:
            a = m + 1
        else:
            b = m - 1

    # uncomment for decimal answers when x is not a perfect cube
    # return sign * x ** (1/3)

    return sign * b
```

Tests:

```
>>> int_cube_root(216)
6
>>> int_cube_root(215)
5
>>> int_cube_root(-27)
-3
>>> int_cube_root(-26)
-2
>>> int_cube_root(77777777777777777777 ** 3)
77777777777777777777
>>> int_cube_root(77777777777777777777 ** 3 - 1)
77777777777777777776
```

Answer (score 0):

In `round` you can decide how many decimals you want to keep. You should also use `1/3` instead of `0.333`

```
cube_num = float(input('X: '))
cube_pow = 1/3
cube_root = cube_num ** cube_pow
print(f'Result: {round(cube_root, 4)}')
# Result: 6.3496
```

You can also avoid casting back to `str` if you use f-string.

Answer (score 0):

The round() method takes two parameters:

```
number - the number that is to be rounded

ndigits (Optional) - number up to which the given number is to be rounded
```

In Python, If you use just round() without ndigits parameter, it rounds to an integer.

Fixed code:

```
cube_Num = float(input(" X: "))
cube_Pow = 0.333
cube_Root = cube_Num**cube_Pow
print(" Result: " + str(round(cube_Root, 2)))
```

> X: 255
>
> Result: 6.33